# HTML and CSS drop down option

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I created a very simple menu bar in HTML with CSS. [WEBSITE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjLNl.png)
I wanted to have a drop-down selection when I hover my mouse in the services link.  I wanted these option to be displayed there: OptionA, OptionB, OptionC (sample only).

More power and thank you so much.

My index code and css code below:

```css
#menu {
  width: 550px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 8px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #333333;
  background-color: #8AD9FF;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
#menu li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 20px;
}
#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00F;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}
#menu a:hover {
  color: #F90;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>MY WEBSITE</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<div align="center">

  <body>

    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: A simple research would help you achieve this. StackOverflow is not a free coding service, we're here to help, not code for you. Please check [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to give your services li a class of "dropbtn". then create another div with a class of "dropdown-content" and give the three options within anchor elements.

check out this resource http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp and look at the last example

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond and I am now working to make it possible.

Answer (score 0):

W3Schools have a good [example](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp) on how to make it work. You can also try some framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).